# Android - setAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm attempting to populate a list in a ListView.
The Fragment I'm using is a tab in my activity.
When I'm trying to create the adapter for the ListView, I encounter an issue.
The adapter I've created TaskItemAdapter up to this point was used in an activity in which there were no tabs, so the contractor was:

```
    public TaskItemAdapter(Context context, List<Task> list) {
    this.itemList = list;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}
```

This is the initialization:

```
list.setAdapter(new TaskItemAdapter(context, itemList));
```

But when I try this in a Fragment, I encounter an issue, as there is no Context to transfer to the contractor.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `getActivity()` instead of `context` in your Fragment:

```
list.setAdapter(new TaskItemAdapter(getActivity(), itemList));
```